# What's the recommended way to migrate from Kendo UI for jQuery to Kendo UI for Angular2?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Disclaimer: I have zero experience with Telerik products, but see Kendo UI as something that's definitely interesting to work with. I have worked with Angular2 and other component-based frameworks before.

I recently received an existing code base that makes use of Kendo UI for jQuery (specifically the 2016 Q1 SP1 version), and got tasked with migrating to a component-based design. Search results gave me Kendo UI for Angular2, which seems like an excellent choice. An interesting thing to note for me, is that it's still a release candidate -- it has been released less than a month ago, as of time of writing, but according to the text on the web page it's production-ready.

At first glance they seem partially compatible (as in same components, and similar APIs), and I have some ideas on how to migrate, but would appreciate input of others (that are more experienced with the previous and current Kendo UI types) on this matter.

Some ideas I have:

- Run both versions simultaneously, and migrate entire pages. This way they won't interfere with each other, and anything encountered that can be turned into a component or service can be converted.
- Put the entire thing into a Angular2 application, and use both Kendo UI for jQuery and Kendo UI for Angular2 on the same pages until everything is migrated. I'm uncertain whether there will be any conflicts here, but I think this is possible with proper encapsulation.

I'm definitely interested in other views regarding this, as more experienced people have probably already solved this issue.

Comment: What's the framework used on the existing code base? AngularJS?

Comment: Unfortunately, none. It's a bunch of jQuery plugin-style code connecting to Kendo Datasources. Pages are served via a Django instance.

Comment: In your situation I'd rewrite an Angular2 app from scratch. Using jquery KendoUI in an Angular2 app is discouraged (and not supported) by telerik. Be careful with the RC version of KendoUI for Angular2, for the moment it is far from matching the features of the jQuery version. For example there is no complete datepicker atm, but a calendar that you can manage to embed in a popup more or less painfully.

Comment: That is what I was dreading, but it appears to be the only sensible solution.